# What issue would arise if all humans worked together?

Tags: internal-consistency, society, hard-science

In the distant future of 2016, a super-intelligent race of hive-minded aliens bestows a "gift" to mankind: a psycho-pathogenetic organism that invades the  mind and erases the concepts of fear, dignity, morality, and self-preservation,  and replaces them with a single, overriding urge to benefit the collective, which the infected human will go to any length to fulfill, thinking almost entirely in terms of logic. The pathogen infects every living human, world peace is promptly attained, and, from then on, mankind pools all of its resources to accomplish tasks

My Question: Is there any major detrimental issue that might end humanity (or at least greatly negatively affect it) that is being overlooked in this scenario?

Comment: Does the infection also enhance the host's logic and reasoning capabilities?

Comment: You do know what happened to the tower of Babel, right?

Comment: All of those things you want the pathogen to destroy?  Those were survival advantages inherited by our ancestors.  Meaning the ancestral humans who lacked them (or exhibited them less strongly) died out.  It's not a certainty but it certainly seems likely that the removal of those drives would be a disadvantage to our species.  An alien hive mind who inflicted such a disease on us, against our will, could only be considered hostile (and full of hubris to boot).

Comment: Unless you have a different definition of peace than I do I cannot see how  peace can exist without morality. Also, agreed with the Tower of Babel comment.

Comment: @Jim2B They were wiped out because they were less self-preserving. If all humans were not self preserving it might turn out differently.

Comment: @XandarTheZenon, the tower of babel is just an hoax, the reality is that some guys pocketed the cash and started building with cheap inferior materials, then pretended to not understand the language when people asked for explanations. ;) If mankind worked together then we would be still discussing, very peacefully, about what would be the first task.

Comment: @Sam, game theory can show that such genetic predispositions are not stable in the gene pool.  If one individual is even slightly more self-preserving than the rest, that individual is far more likely to survive to pass on its genes.  The same is true for violence and the rest.  The individual that's more aggressive inherits significant individual & genetic advantages over the rest of the herd.  This means those traits are more likely to spread widely and over time we'll end up with individuals exhibiting traits very like what they do now - because today's configuration IS genetically stable.

Comment: @Jim2B Yes but if all humans were artificially forced to work together...?

Comment: Then all the advantage goes to the one person who is a little more selfish and a little less altruistic.  You are the genetic equivalent of a ball balanced on top of a pyramid.  Any slight disturbance pushes the whole gene pool back to something more resembling what we have here.  I highly recommend reading "The Selfish Gene."  It's a very interesting read and it explains all this quite well.

Comment: You can start with this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionarily_stable_strategy .  Pure altruism is not an evolutionarily stable strategy.  Cheaters prosper the most in such a gene pool.  Those who don't "cheat" but simply aren't quite as altruistic do much better than the pure altruists.  Even if it is possible to make people that way, as soon as you stop messing with their genetics, the population will shift away.  Given the description of your society, the advantages to cheating are so huge, the "cheater" (selfish) gene will propagate through the population like wildfire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Worst case: Doom by Synchronicity

A global newscast tells of a major setback in the attempt to increase food production. All humans who see this newscast (and more will than currently, because it benefits the collective) come to the same conclusion: The population needs to be reduced. Each and every one of them commits suicide at the same time, leaving the Earth mostly depopulated. Refer to many posts on this forum about the problems the "survivors" will face while attempting to restore civilization.

### Who governs?

There are no laws suitable to the new situation. This would not be a problem as agreement is suddenly easy to reach, except for two small glitches:

1. 99% of politicians immediately resign, declaring themselves intellectually and morally unfit to govern their country/region/city.
2. People of different intelligence come to different conclusions on what the best solutions might be, causing all of them to cluster into like-minded groups that will (amicably) argue endlessly over which is the better plan for the collective. Compromises take years to reach, preventing governments from becoming effective.

### I'll save you!: Accident Chains

While workplace accidents are greatly reduced because of people not being lazy/fraudulent anymore, lack of fear and self-preservation will shift the balance right back as any human will gladly risk their life and limb to prevent a reduction in productivity or save someone else.

Typical scenario:

A truck with badly needed medicine that will save hundreds of lives blows a tire and the driver loses control of it on a highway overpass. Each of the drivers around the truck recognizes the markings on the truck and is aware of its priority, but doesn't have the skill to accurately predict what will happen. Several of them attempt to steer/straighten the truck by ramming it from the side, getting themselves crushed or thrown over the side of the bridge instead. More cars will brake in front of the truck, getting crushed and run over. The truck driver will do ANYTHING to prevent the truck from going overt the edge, so when faced with the choice of sides in a moment of control, he jumps the divider and rushes into oncoming traffic.

**Total death count: 35 people.** This is still a net gain as hundreds might have been lost if the medicine was destroyed. Except that the factory could have doubled its output and replaced the lost medicine. Sadly, the drivers involved were not aware of this.

### What about the children?

This is the kicker: Children are not born with advanced logic. Their brains develop as they grow, and fear and self-preservation instincts are vital in keeping them safe during this period.

The obvious answer seems to be for adults to carefully watch their child 24/7 and protect them from all harm and setbacks. There is a serious price to pay for that though in terms of mental development. Lack of risk, danger and difficult/impossible challenges means the brain isn't able to "calibrate" itself to deal with those things. The result would be young adults that are (by force) deeply committed to the collective, but simply unable to handle difficult, dangerous or otherwise stressful situations without supervision.

In short: If the children are infected, they will either suffer from high accident and death rates or they will be raised in a way will causes problems down the line when there are no more of the pre-infection population alive.

If they are not infected or the change doesn't happen until adulthood, you will have parents unable to understand or deal with their childrens' ambivalent and egocentric (i.e. normal human) behavior, because they lost all capability to empathize with those feelings. This will lead to some awesome teenage revolts.

### The Outcome

All hostility has ceased and humanity decommissions its entire arsenal.

Twenty years later, the aliens arrive to take possession of their new world full of docile worker drones.

Answer (score 3):

This actually enters some really interesting philosophical grounds.  The first question would be whether we can define what benefits the collective?  If I may rephrase that, let's change out "benefits the collective" with "benefits humanity."  After all, the collective is humanity.

**It turns out coming up with a word or phrase which benefits humanity in all cases is *remarkably* hard.  It's even harder to do so using only words with clear definitions.**  "All you need is love" could probably benefit humanity in all cases, but pinning a good definition to "love" has been a task for the poets for millennia.

In fact, it can't be done with logic.  At least, you can't prove it.  There's some nasty quirks that come up when you try to define humanity in a way which permits logic to be applied to it.  If you care, look up Godel's Incompleteness Theorem, or take my word for it: you can't actually create a logical system which can prove that it, itself, is beneficial for humanity (as long as you include arithmetic, and the "negation" operator from predicate logic).  Thus, no human acting purely for the benefit of humanity could come up with it.  Annoying self-referential loops start to form, and Godel proved that you can never remove all of them.  **Moral of the story: there will be *some* part of "beneficial to humanity" which is not purely logical.**  This isn't a bad thing, it just means logic isn't everything.

If you are willing to overlook this logical quagmire, and accept that there is some way we can all act towards the benefit of all humanity, some interesting patterns can show up.  How confident are you that fear, dignity, morality, and self-preservation are all detriments to humanity?  We did evolve many of these traits because they are useful.  Even with all humans working together, Earth is a dangerous place, full of powers well beyond ours like natural disasters.  We may need fear or dignity to deal with these, or perhaps we may need them to deal with aliens in the future!  **Thus, in a twist of fate, the human collective may decide that, for the benefit of humanity, we need to re-develop those emotions the aliens gifted away from us in the first place!**

In fact, the most effective approach might be for the alien organism to rely on patience and setalth.  Perhaps the human collective decides, unanimously, that the best path forward for all of humanity is for us to believe we have regained our independence, wipe all of our memories of the alien gift, and go forward with our lives.  Perhaps the alien organism merely sits in the background and encourages us to become one collective, rather than forcing us like it tried to do at first.  **You can only lead a horse to water; you can't make him drink.**

Perhaps the organism is most vocal in the works of the artists: the musicians, the painters, the sculptors.  They would be more in tune with the messages the organism wants to instill in us.  Perhaps it encourages them to produce work trying to capture that quintessential essence of what makes us human.  What is common to all of us.  Perhaps we've heard the songs inspired by this organism before, made famous with their words:

> ♫ All you need is love
>   All you need is love
>   All you need is love, love
>   Love is all you need! ♫

Comment: Not to mention "the good of the collective" is often fatal to a subset of that collective (as communism has shown every time it was given a chance).  Who decides which party of the collective should perish?  Many people assume that violence, tribalism, et al are defects in the human species.  Yet it was these traits that evolution selected for - they provided survival advantages to our ancestors.  Maybe the defectives are those that don't want those things?

Answer (score 1):

Logic and cooperation would promote consensus solutions based on "scientific orthodoxy." There would be fewer people "thinking out of the box" because it is not logical to assume that they will succeed where others have failed. Much more logical to work on the incremental improvement of existing technology.

Most of the people who challenge the scientific mainstream are simply crackpots. But every now and then somebody comes around with a badly needed fresh perspective.